# Origin of $\alpha(a) = \alpha\left[1+ \frac{4}{3\pi}\alpha R(a) \right]^2$?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, regularization

My professors note on vertex function make some doubts in me,
$$\Lambda_\rho(p,q,p')=\frac{e^2 \gamma_\rho}{3\pi^2}R(a)$$,Where $\Lambda_\rho(p,q,p')$ is the electron-photon vertex at one-loop level
,
In terms of the fine structure constant $\alpha(a) = \frac{e^2(a)}{4\pi}$ the one loop contribution
to the QED vertex can be casted in the form
$$
\alpha(a) = \alpha\left[1+ \frac{4}{3\pi}\alpha R(a) \right]^2, \label{alpha1}
$$

I don't understand how he got the second equation, please give me some ideas...

Comment: What is the definition of the vertex function?

Comment: I just mean a general fermion-photon vertex @G. Smith